# How to avoid this error when trying to copy a specific folder from my local system to remote VM using winrm in Jenkins configuration?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, continuous-deployment

Am using Powershell script to copy a folder from local system to remote VM.

The below script works fine when am running from my local system.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName dummy.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My

winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="dummy.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com"; CertificateThumbprint="9C207E7D249D385FDE9D4BBFE7AF7EB008RDGD"}

$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String <Password>
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - argumentlist <username>,$pw
$session = new-pssession -computername dummy.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com -credential $cred
Copy-Item -Path C:\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-service\bin.zip -Destination F:\destpath\bin1.zip -ToSession $session
```

But when I use the same script in Jenkins at the build step. It throws me an error as given below.

> "WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x8009030d occurred while using Negotiate authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

**What I tried So Far  to resolve this error:**

1. I have ensured that winrm is setup on both the host machines involved. Infact with 'Unrestricted' access via set-ExecutionPolicy.
2. I have Ensured remote machine running as a non-domain user, because local machine is running as a non-domain user.
3. Used Invoke-Command.

Comment: Did you try using `Invoke-Command` instead of New-PSSession?

Comment: There is a space between `-` and `argumentlist` where you create the `$cred` variable. Are you sure your credentials are correct?

Comment: I would also check if `$session` is a valid object, add `if ($null -ne $session) { Copy-Item ... } `

Comment: There was also a bug related to the `Copy-Item` PSSession feature, where both (source, destination) need the same drive names. Not sure if it related to this one, but you could give it a try -> https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11306682-bug-copy-item-fromsession-fails-if-local-machine.

Comment: @Vijay Rajendiran, please also provide the used PowerShell versions in the source and remote machine.

Comment: @Modro , I will try with Invoke-command

Comment: @Theo yes the credentials are correct, it's working when running from my local Powershell.

Comment: @Moerwald, the version is 5.1.17134.858.  The same version is using in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Change in this line, fixed my issue.

```
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - argumentlist <username>,$pw 
as
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - argumentlist <domainname>\<username>,$pw
```

PSCredential, would expect the credential to be with domainname\username rather than passing username alone.